# PHP to Postgres, Pass a date variable from a form to PHP to excute a query

Tags: php, forms, postgresql, variables

Ok so I was posed this bit of coding.  It is a PGSQL query that I use in PHP to display on a HTML page.  I am using the correct PHP to get it to display for a manually entered date.  What I want to do is replace the last line of the PGSQL:

```
SELECT cm."ID",a."ID" as "DSI",cm."Date",c."Amount",ct."Name" as "Name",cm."Comments" as "Comments"
FROM "Memo" cm
LEFT JOIN "Credit" c ON (c."ID" = cm."CreditID")
LEFT JOIN "Account" a ON (c."AccountID" = a."ID")
LEFT JOIN "CreditMemoReason" ct ON (ct."ID" = cm."CreditMemoReasonID")
WHERE cm."Date" >= '2011-09-01' AND cm."Date" < '2011-10-01';
```

I want to have the variable passed from the HTML form to PHP so that once the user hits submit it excutes the Query with the date selected.  Really the above shows a full date. I am only wanting to have the select be a month only from a drop down select box and then the date entered will be 2011-09-01 thru 2011-10-01 as September, or 2011-08-01 thru 2011-09-01 for August and so on.  I really need some help doing so.

My php looks like this right now to display the query:

```
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' .
pg_last_error());
// Printing results in HTML
echo "<h2 align=center>Revenue Report</h2>";
echo "<table align=center border=1 solid width=500px>\n";
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
  echo "\t<tr>\n";
  foreach ($line as $col_value) {
      echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
  }
  echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";// Free resultset
pg_free_result($result);// Closing connection
pg_close($dbconn);
```

Comment: Display code is irrelevant until you get your query figured out. Show the SQL you've got right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **plpgsql function** for that (stored procedure).

#### Edit: much simpler like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test(integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(
 "ID"       integer  -- !guessing your data types, you may have to adjust!
,"DSI"      integer
,"Date"     date
,"Amount"   integer
,"Name"     text
,"Comments" text) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  mydate    date := (to_char(now(), 'YYYY') || '-' || $1::text || '-1')::date;
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
SELECT cm."ID"
      ,a."ID" -- AS "DSI"
      ,cm."Date"
      ,c."Amount"
      ,ct."Name"
      ,cm."Comments"
  FROM "Memo" cm
  LEFT JOIN "Credit" c ON (c."ID" = cm."CreditID")
  LEFT JOIN "Account" a ON (c."AccountID" = a."ID")
  LEFT JOIN "CreditMemoReason" ct ON (ct."ID" = cm."CreditMemoReasonID")
 WHERE cm."Date" >= mydate AND cm."Date" < (mydate + interval '1 month')::date;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call (for November):

```
SELECT * FROM f_test(11);
```

#### Major points:

- I **assumed** you want the current year. You did not tell.
- Edit: no special case for December needed, just add interval.
- If you enter an invalid month you trigger an error.
- Be careful not to use the OUT parameters as unqualified column names. (name conflict!) That's why I commented that out: -- AS "DSI"
- Some column aliases were redundant

#### General advice on PostgreSQL functions

- The manual on [server programming](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/server-programming.html) in general and [plpgsql functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) in particular.
- [CREATE FUNCTION syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html)
- Use RETURNS TABLE to define the return type.
- Use [RETURN QUERY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) to return from function.
- You can use [pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org/) to administer your database more conveniently.
- I would advise *not* to use [mixed case identifiers in postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html), makes your life easier.

Comment: SO with this I would just pass the mydate variable from the form. correct, seems that is where the logic is. I guess what I will do is a select box with the dates calling the select box mydate and then each of the selection values as 01-12 correct?

Comment: @DoCnTex: Yeah, you send `SELECT * FROM f_test(11);` to the server and get the results for November. You just have to fill in the month in the simple query. As the function is compiled and the query plan can be cached, this will also be faster than sending the whole query every time - unless you expect a *very* different number of rows for different monts, then basic SQL could be faster.

Comment: The term is plpgsql for the procedural language. You create the function by sending the above SQL to the server like you would send any query. I'll add a couple of links to my answer where you can read about the basics. PostgreSQL has an excellent manual.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select name="startdate">
<option value="2014-01-01">2014-01-01</option>
</select>
```

PHP:

```
$startdate = pg_escape_string($_REQUEST['startdate']);

$query = <<<SQL
SELECT cm."ID",a."ID" as "DSI",cm."Date",c."Amount",ct."Name" as "Name",cm."Comments" as "Comments"
FROM "Memo" cm
LEFT JOIN "Credit" c ON (c."ID" = cm."CreditID")
LEFT JOIN "Account" a ON (c."AccountID" = a."ID")
LEFT JOIN "CreditMemoReason" ct ON (ct."ID" = cm."CreditMemoReasonID")
WHERE cm."Date" >= {$startdate} AND cm."Date" < ({$startdate}+ interval '1 month')::date;
SQL;
```